# Why does yield return generator object even if condition is false

Tags: python

This code gives "no" in result:

```
def question(truth=False):
    if not truth:
        return("no")
    else:
        return("yes")

print(question())
```

This code gives "<generator object question at 0x000001A1E548CC80>" in result:

```
def question(truth=False):
    if not truth:
        return("no")
    else:
        yield("yes")

print(question())
```

Why does the second one give different result? Condition for yield is not met.

Comment: *Any function containing a yield [keyword is a generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators); this is detected by Python’s bytecode compiler which compiles the function specially as a result.*

Answer (score 6):

Because calling a function with a `yield` statement always creates a generator. The function only executes when you iterate over the generator, not when you call the function initially.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Having a "yield" keyword anywhere in a function/method will immediately make that function/method a generator and thus unable to ever return. It doesn't matter whether the yield keyword is even reachable, its existence is enough.